# Dragging over touchable opacity on React-Native Web

Tags: react-native-web

### Problem

Using react native web, I am trying to allow for drag to work over a touchable opacity. This will allow mobile users to scroll by dragging over the touchable opacity.

### Attempts

Since there are two touchable opacities within a single view, I have been trying to fix it for the view (parent) so that it works for the whole section. So, within the view tag, I have tried handles like: onResponderRelease, onResponderStart, onStartShouldSetResponder, onStartShouldSetResponderCapture, and a few others in an attempt to find something that works, as it seems those handles would fix issues for react native. I have assigned them to false and true, however none of those fixed my issue.

### Question

How can I allow components to maintain their ability to be clicked, while also allowing users to click and drag (scroll on mobile)? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you referring to this https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/1534